# WhereNotExists Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Little bit of trouble with the eloquent framework for laravel.

I need to replicate a query like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM RepairJob
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT repair_job_id
    FROM DismissedRequest
    WHERE RepairJob.id = DismissedRequest.repair_job_id);
```

Right now I have

```
 $repairJobs = RepairJob::with('repairJobPhoto', 'city', 'vehicle')->where('active', '=', 'Y')->whereNotExists('id', [DismissedRequest::all('repair_job_id')])->get();
```

Anyone an idea? I need to get all the repairjobs where there is no record for in the dismissed requests table

I get this error when using the query above

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereNotExists() must be an instance of Closure, string given
```

Comment: `whereNotExists` takes a function and alters the `$query`. See the docs for `whereExists` here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres

Comment: that's not eloquent?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try doesntHave() method. Assuming 'dismissedRequests' as relation name in RepairJob model.

```
$jobs = RepairJob::with('repairJobPhoto', 'city', 'vehicle')
    ->where('active', 'Y')->doesntHave('dismissedRequests')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, however if I change that one line of code to this I get the error mentioned in the update above. any ideas?

Comment: So, I guess that you use barryvdh/laravel-cors package for CORS handling. Make sure that you apply `cors` middleware to a route or group to add CORS support. Example: `Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(Router $router){
    $router->get('api', 'ApiController@index');
});`. Another way is adding `cors` as global middleware, if you want to apply it for all your routes.

Comment: Thanks, this code is clean and works, the problem was an syntax error :) :)

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
$repairJobs = RepairJob::with('repairJobPhoto', 'city', 'vehicle')
              ->where('active', '=', 'Y')
              ->whereNotExists(function($query)
                {
                    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                          ->from('DismissedRequest')
                          ->whereRaw('RepairJob.id = DismissedRequest.id');
                })->get();
```

Comment: Got the same error as with the code from Phargelm, please see the update above, any ideas? Thanks for replying

Comment: Yest this is CORS - configure properly your server (appache, nginx, ?) and create new question - don't mix this two question here.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I used it as local scope and it works pretty well

Comment: I recommend using `whereColumn` instead of `whereRaw`

Comment: This works also for non-Eloquent querie builder