# Eloquent scope - all items not a FK in other table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

First, a little background to understand the diffiulty I have with creating a query scope.

Here is part of my schema:

```
Structure
 - id
 - head_office_id

Establishment
 - id
 - structure_id
```

Here is how the relationships are defined in my models

```
class Structure {    
    public function head_office(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Establishment::class, 'head_office_id');
    }

    public function establishments(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Establishment::class);
    }

}

class Establishment {
    public function structure(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Structure::class);
    }
}
```

I would like to make a scope on establishments which can exclude all establishments which are the head-office of the structure they belong to.

```
Establishment::notHeadOffice()->get()
```

For instance:

```
Structures

id | head_office_id
1  | null
2  | 3

Establishments

id | structure_id
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 2
5  | 2
```

In that case, the scope should bring back all establishments **but** number 3 (because establishment 3 is linked to structure 2 and is the head-office of that structure)

I have tried a few things but this gets beyond my knowledge of the query builder.

Any clues?

PS: model cannot be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build query in scope method.

The following code works..

**Establishment.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class Establishment extends Model
{

    public function scopeNotHeadOffice($query)
    {
        return $query->whereNotExists(function ($qry) {
            $qry->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('structures')
                ->whereRaw('structures.head_office_id = establishments.id');
        });
    }

    public function structure(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Structure::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
Establishment::notHeadOffice()->get();
```

References:

Laravel WhereExists - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-exists-clauses

Laravel WhereNotExists- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38575266

MySQL exists- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-exists/

Comment: Test passes! Thanks a lot.